# Celery task queue not blocking to single thread - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I'm trying to reproduce example from Celery official Task Cookbook (link: [Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#id1)) and I can't figure out why my Celery task queue is not blocked to single thread.

So here is my code snippet (it is almost exactly the same as in the official doc):

```py
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from django.core.cache import cache

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 10

@contextmanager
def memcache_lock(lock_id, oid):
    timeout_at = time.monotonic() + LOCK_EXPIRE - 3
    status = cache.add(lock_id, oid, LOCK_EXPIRE)

    try:
        yield status
    finally:
        if time.monotonic() < timeout_at and status:
            cache.delete(lock_id)


@shared_task(bind=True, name="print_text")
def print_text(self, text):
    text_hexdigest = md5(text.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
    lock_id = "{0}-lock-{1}".format(self.name, text_hexdigest)

    logger.debug("Printing text: %s", text)
    with memcache_lock(lock_id, self.app.oid) as acquired:
        if acquired:
            import time
            time.sleep(5)
            return
    logger.debug("Print_text %s is already being imported by another worker", text)
```

When I call the `print_text` function several times, the **first call should block the second (and all subsequent) calls - this is expected behavior**:

```py
# ./manage.py shell
from django_celery_example.celery import print_text
task = print_text.delay('John')
task = print_text.delay('John')
```

But when I check the Celery output, both tasks run in parallel, without thread blocking (look at the time difference between the first and the second call - **the first call does not block thread for 5 seconds**!!!).

```bash
[2023-05-29 15:59:12,098: INFO/MainProcess] Task print_task[92155dfa-c31c-4523-b230-6bb69e65f538] received
[2023-05-29 15:59:12,468: INFO/MainProcess] Task print_task[e7d3f76b-0647-4892-80e1-5cf43bda331e] received

[2023-05-29 15:59:17,118: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-16] Task print_task[92155dfa-c31c-4523-b230-6bb69e65f538] succeeded in 5.0151121219987544s: None
[2023-05-29 15:59:17,486: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task print_task[e7d3f76b-0647-4892-80e1-5cf43bda331e] succeeded in 5.014470825000899s: None
```

So, I don't get it - what I'm doing wrong? And why Celery threads aren't been blocked and executed simultaneously instead? I checked examples of this pattern realization in open-source repositories on GitHub, but they all use the same code :( Maybe I'm missing something?